# What's the name of these type of functions?

Tags: functions

Trivial question. Consider these "multiplicative" functions $y = f(x,w,z)$:

$$ y = xwz $$

$$ y = \frac{x^2}{wz} $$

where $x, w, z$ are all positive.

They key is that all terms are multiplicating each other, and there are no summation terms, nor logarithms or exponents. So examples which I do not want are:

$$ y = 2+xwz $$

$$ y = \frac{2+x^2}{wz} $$

$$ y = \ln(x)\frac{z+1}{e^w} $$

Thus, **all I want is that the function is homogeneous and "subterms" are "multiplicative"**. Homogeneous but not "multiplicative" functions do not qualify (e.g. $y = x + w + z$).

The question is: **what's the name for this type of functions (if any)?** I thought it would be "[multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function)" but that seems to be another type altogether, related to prime numbers which have nothing to do with my case.

Comment: Polynomials with one term are called monomials. For example, $xwz$ is a monomial. But I don't know if there is a name for functions with a single term in general.

Comment: @A.Goodier Thanks! So it would be an homogeneous monomial? (probably all monomials are by definition homogeneous) Although, I do allow for negative exponents, which seems not to be the case in monomials.

Comment: Yes, that's right, all monomials are homogeneous.

Comment: @A.Goodier So basically, my case is that of a fraction of mononials.

Comment: Your example $x^2/(wz)$ is a quotient of monomials, but not a monomial itself